# What is SCS in arm64 architecture? (register x18 is used for SCS stack pointer)

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm, arm64

In [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10-rc5/source/arch/arm64/kernel/entry.S#L926) I see the definition of `cpu_switch_to` function which is the essential part of the linux context switch. In the function body there is another macro `scs_save` or `scs_load`. Following the definition I see a register `scs_sp` is used and from [here](https://git.0l.de/Mirrors/linux/commit/711e8b0de0d63c70c825b473da01288b661a2386) I could see `scs_sp` is an alias for `x18` register  and it said x18 is used for SCS stack pointer. What is SCS? I couldn't find it in the armv8 architecutre document or anywhere else.

Comment: `#ifdef CONFIG_SHADOW_CALL_STACK` ... so, SCS = Shadow Call Stack.